# Confidence interval for poisson regression

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, standard-error, poisson-regression

I understand that for linear regression, the confidence interval is the smallest at (mean of Y, mean of X).

However, I am trying to understand why this is not the case if I were fit the data using GLM and setting the family to poisson.

```
set.seed(1)
#-------------------------
X = rpois(n=10000,lambda=100)
B1 = 0.74723
B2 = 0.09646
r.error = rpois(n=10000,lambda=0.05)
Y = exp(B1+B2*X)+r.error
F = data.frame(Y,X)

##GLM fitting-------------------------
F.test = data.frame(X=seq(90,120,1))
F.fit.p = glm(Y~X,data=F,family=poisson)
F.pred.p = predict(F.fit.p,newdata = F.test,se.fit=T)
F.pred.p$se.fit

#lm fitting---------------------------
F.fit.g = glm(log(Y)~X,data=F,family=gaussian)
F.pred.g = predict(F.fit.g,newdata = F.test,se.fit=T)
F.pred.g$se.fit
```

[image]

As seen in the diagram above, for X with a mean of approximately 100. The SE of the fit under gaussian is the smallest when X=100 while the SE of the fit under poisson seems to be the smallest at X=110.

Comment: Note that you're not simulating Poisson-distributed data properly.  You want to take random draws from a Poisson distribution with mean exp(B1+B2*X), not add a Poisson-distributed error term to a mean exp(B1+B2*X).

Comment: Could you please tell me more about what you mean by taking random draws from a Poisson distribution with mean exp(B1+B2*X)? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I figured out the answer. You need the covariance matrix to calculate the SE (see http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/2289). And doing some rearrangement, you see that the minimum SE occurs at mean(X)+Beta*mean(X) = 110

Comment: If you figured out the answer, can you please post that as a complete answer yourself, so that the question is not lingering as unanswered?